# Transfer files using socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a server-client socket chat application,
at the server folder I have a game folder where I have a javascript game that I wrote,pictures of the game, and an html page to run the game.
When the client writing the command "@game" the server will send him the game files, and the client will download the game files to a C directory.
I have tried to transfer the files in couple of ways all of them seem to fail, It's look like the html file and the JS files transfer completely but the pictures aren't complete and that's why the game isn't working...

I need to transfer the files using only sockets.

**Server Side**

I used the SendFile method and after every file data I sent "\d" for a sign to move to the next data so that client could know the different between files data.

```
        public static bool Game(string msg, Socket socket)
    {
        if (msg.Equals("@game"))
        {
            ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string path = @"G:\הנדסת תוכנה\כיתה יא\ChatProject\ServerChat\game";
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes("@game"));
            Byte[] preBuffer = asc.GetBytes("@download ");
            Byte[] postBuffer = asc.GetBytes("@End");

            socket.SendFile(path + @"\SpaceShip.js");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\page.html");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\background.jpg");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\defeat.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\enemyspaceship.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\friendlyspaceship.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\IMG_06062017_225026_0.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\laser.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            socket.SendFile(path + @"\Images\victory.png");
            socket.Send(asc.GetBytes(@"\d"));
            Console.WriteLine("Game was send to "+socket.RemoteEndPoint);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Client Side**

At the client side I first created the directory, and let myself to write the order of the files sending, at the Download function I moved every 2 char to check if I have the "\d" sign that I have sent, If I came across one I know it's the end of the data file and I write the data over the file I create.

```
  public static void Game()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("downloading and opening the game...");
        string path = @"C:\Game";
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path+@"\Images");
        Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully ");
        Console.WriteLine("reciving Data");
        string[] pathArr = new string[]
        {
            path + @"\SpaceShip.js",
            path + @"\page.html",
            path + @"\Images\background.jpg",
            path + @"\Images\defeat.png",
            path + @"\Images\enemyspaceship.png",
            path + @"\Images\friendlyspaceship.png",
            path + @"\Images\IMG_06062017_225026_0.png",
            path + @"\Images\laser.png",
            path + @"\Images\victory.png"
        };
        Download(pathArr);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + @"\page.html");
    }
    public static void Download(string [] pathArr)
    {

        byte[] binDataIn = new byte[1025];
        int k = socket.Receive(binDataIn, 0, 1025, SocketFlags.None);
        ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string rcv = asc.GetString(binDataIn, 0, k);
        string data = "";
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (j<=8)
        {
            string sign = rcv[i].ToString() + rcv[i + 1].ToString();
            if (sign.Equals( @"\d"))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(pathArr[j], data);
                data = "";
                j++;
                i += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                data += rcv[i];
                i++;
            }

            if(rcv.Length-1<=i)
            {
                 k = socket.Receive(binDataIn, 0, 1025, SocketFlags.None);
                 rcv = asc.GetString(binDataIn, 0, k);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I might complicated the process and there is a simpler way...
thanks to all the responding.

Comment: The files might contain \d in them so it’s not reliable. Not performant. Why not prefix with length so you know how much data to get per file?

Comment: I tried before with specific length to every file but for some reason, the images were still not complete, it didn't appear in the html file and when I tried to view the pictures from the folders it failed to view.
Maybe images should transfer differently?

Comment: you seem to be converting the byte stream to a string using `ASCIIEncoding`. that cannot process image files (or any binary files) reliably because it will omit or encode control characters. also I think the `data` variable is never written to?

Comment: Also, all your resources are <= 1025 bytes? If you insist on sending binary files as text (but why though?), you'll need to use an encoding like Base64.

Comment: thank you, I think I have got my mistake, I am not in front of my pc right now I will try what you said later.

Comment: thank you all, your comment have helped me.